# REST API using ASP.NET Database FIRST - DataAnnotations Multiple Columns, 1 primary key ("ID")

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, data-annotations

Good Morning

I’m attempting to build a REST API using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core. 
It’s my first venture into this territory using DATABASE FIRST.

This tutorial is helping https://chsakell.com/2016/06/23/rest-apis-using-asp-net-core-and-entity-framework-core/ however I’m having difficulty when my table DOES NOT have a primary key (“ID”), rather a primary key would be constructed off multiple columns (the DBA thinks ID columns on every table is just a bad habit)

Example my performance returns table in our Database. 
A portfolio can only have 1 set of performance returns statistics for that day. The primary key for this table would work off PortfolioCode and ValueDate.

In my Returns Model.cs is there a way using the Column attribute to construct something like the following.

Model: Returns.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Scheduler.Model
{

public class CashMovement : IEntityBase

{
[Column("PortfolioCode")("ValueDate")]
public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PortfoioCode { get; set; }
    public date ValueDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Return { get; set; }
}}
```

This obviously errors but the tutorial uses an ID column from an interface for all its models

Model: IEntityBase.cs

```
namespace Scheduler.Model
{
public interface IEntityBase
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
}
```

Repository IRepository.cs

```
using Scheduler.Model;

namespace Scheduler.Data.Abstract
{
public interface IReturnsRepository: IEntityBaseRepository< Returns > { }
}
```

Repository: ReturnsRepository.cs

```
using Scheduler.Model;

namespace Scheduler.Data.Abstract
{
public interface IReturnsRepository : IEntityBaseRepository<Returns> { }
}
```

ViewModel: CashMovementViewModel.cs

```
using Scheduler.API.ViewModels.Validations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

namespace Scheduler.API.ViewModels
{
  public class ReturnsViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    **[Column("PortfolioCode")("ValueDate")]
    public int Id { get; set; }**

    public string PortfoioCode { get; set; }
    public date ValueDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Return { get; set; }

 }
 }
```

Thanks Gws

Comment: why can't you setup a composite key on the table ? then you can use [Key, Column(Order=0)] ,[Key, Column(Order=1)]attributes to specify key fields

Comment: Ok done, I have setup the table in the database with a composite key or PortfolioCode then ValueDate... would you be able to help me adapt this into my model? to make the Id field?

Comment: Here is MSDN article talking about composite PK and EF. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Composite

Comment: Thanks for the article. Do you think there is a way to implement the interface member ID with this approach?